# Can't mount old TM backup sparsebundle on Apple Time Capsule

Tags: time-machine, mount, time-capsule, sparsebundle

I have an old ATC (Apple Time capsule) - which used to backup my Mac Mini and my MacAir. The Mac Mini has now died, but I wanted to retrieve some files from the sparsebundle. Unfortunately, I can't get it to mount. I can read the package contents though, and the file size shows 113.4GB.

I tried to `hdiutil attach <>.sparsebundle -nomount -readwrite -noverify -noautofsck` and then I ran `fsck_hfs -dy /dev/disk4` and the output of which was as follows (note no partition scheme/information in `hdiutil`):

```
/dev/disk4                                              
joy@Joy-Nandis-MacAir ~ % fsck_hfs -dy /dev/disk4
journal_replay(/dev/disk4) returned 22
** /dev/rdisk4
    Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=32768 cacheSize=1048576K.
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-627.100.6).
    Block 2 is not an MDB or Volume Header 
    Block 3902834782 is not an MDB or Volume Header 
volumeType is 0
/dev/rdisk4 0000:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
/dev/rdisk4 01f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
    unknown volume type 
    primary MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    primary VHB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate VHB is at block 0 0x00 
    sector size = 512 0x200 
    VolumeObject flags = 0x01 
    total sectors for volume = 3902834784 0xe8a08860 
    total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00 
    CheckForClean - unknown volume type 
    CheckHFS returned 6, fsmodified = 0
```

May I please get some suggestions on how to fix and mount this sparsebundle?